# How to install a new C/C++ library and make it visible in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Hello everybody I'm porting a C/C++ Unix application to Windows. My problem is that I need to download the various Unix native libraries into their windows version and then I have to use them. Doew anyone know what's the procedure to follow to make Visual Studio 2017 recognize the new downloaded libraries? For example, if I had to download the windows version of GnuTLS from this site: https://www.gnutls.org/download.html how should I do to make the library header files visible and usable from visual studio? What's the procedure to follow?

Comment: Short answer: it depends on the package. My recommendation here would be to use software such as CMake which can generate build files for Unix (Makefiles, ninja...) and also Visual Studio projects on Windows. There might be some work involved, but in my experience, maintaining a single build system for a cross-platform program is beneficial in the long run. CMake has a standard way to specify dependencies so that it can generally locate them automatically, while allowing manual control in non-standard environments (like Windows).

Comment: Just to pick at nits, is the library C language or C++ language, as there is no language C/C++?  Also, libraries are language independent.  You could have a FORTRAN library and link it with C++, depends on the toolchain, not the language.

Comment: I have a C++ project that works on Unix, the project already has the CMakeList.txt files for using CMake in the right way. I created a directory "build" inside the project directory, then I moved to it and i run CMake by using cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64". CMake has built a Visual Studio solution but, honestly I'm quite new with CMake and unfortunately I don't know where CMake places the libraries you are talking about @SirDarius

Comment: I can't see them using Visual Studio in fact one of them is GnuTLS so I thought I had to download them manually.

Comment: Well, if CMake has succeeded, your project should build... Otherwise, just check the CMake variables using the GUI, which should list the libraries marked as "NOT-FOUND".